# VueJS 2.0 - Difference between v-on.stop and v-on.prevent?

Tags: vuejs2

Can you please help me clarify the difference between v-on.stop and v-on.prevent?
Both are used to prevent default event, but not sure about the difference.

Answer (score 3):

> Both are used to prevent default event

That is not true:

1. `v-on.stop` = `event.stopPropagation()` - it is used to stop bubbling, so if you have a parent and a child and they both have a click event, and when clicking the child you only want it's event to happen, you'll use this.
2. `v-on.prevent` = `event.preventDefault` - it is used to prevent the default behavior of the clicked element, so if you clicked an `a` tag, it will prevent it from going to the link it points to.